# Pausar Video que se esta reproduciendo cuando se le da play a otro video

Tags: javascript, html, html5, video

Tengo una listas de videos en una web que se generan con el siguiente codigo:

```
if (arch === '.mp4') {
  previo = '<video controls width="70%" preload="metadata" poster="media/imagen/postervideos.png">  <source src="' + ruta + archivo + '" type="video/mp4"></video>';
  boton = "Ver Video en otra ventana" + v;

}
```

Requiero que cuando se le haga click a un video este se ejecute y cuando se le haga click a otro video entonces el primer video se detenga.

He intentado hacerlo funcionar con el siguiente script pero no logro hacerlo funcionar

```
$('video').off('play').on('play', function() {
    var dd = this.id
    $('video').each(function( index ) {
        if(dd != this.id){
            this.pause();
            this.currentTime = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Podrías tener una variable global donde guardes ID del video que se está reproduciendo, cuando hagas clic en otro, detienes el video actual, comienzas la reproducción del nuevo y actualizas la variable.

Comment: Ok ya he creado los id dentro del bucle de esta forma `previo = '<video id="'+narchi+'" controls width="70%" preload="metadata" poster="media/imagen/postervideos.png">  <source src="' + ruta + archivo + '" type="video/mp4"></video>';` ahora como seria la instruccion para que pause el video actual cuando se le da click al play de otro video..?

Comment: Listo lo he hecho funcionar con solo asignarle un id a cada video ya funciona a la perfección..!

Comment: Agrega una respuesta con la solución, seguramente le servirá a alguien más.

Answer (score 1):

He solucionado de la siguiente manera: he creado los id dentro del bucle de esta forma

```
previo = '<video id="'+narchi+'" controls width="70%" preload="metadata" poster="media/imagen/postervideos.png">  <source src="' + ruta + archivo + '" type="video/mp4"></video>';
```

y en la misma function de donde se originan la listas de videos he ingresado el siguiente codigo

```
$('video').off('play').on('play', function() {
    var dd = this.id
    $('video').each(function( index ) {
        if(dd != this.id){
            this.pause();
            this.currentTime = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

de esta manera cuando hay un video en play y hago play a otro video el video que estaba en play se pausa de forma automatica.